# Android 1.6: "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application"

Tags: android, android-dialog, runtimeexception, android-windowmanager

I'm trying to open a dialog window, but every time I try to open it it throws this exception:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: 
     Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:460)
  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:238)
  at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2413)
```

I'm creating it by calling `showDialog` with the display's id. The `onCreateDialog` handler logs fine and I can step through it without an issue, but I've attached it since it seems like I'm missing something:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    Dialog dialog;
    Context appContext = this.getApplicationContext();
    switch(id)
    {
        case RENAME_DIALOG_ID:
            Log.i("Edit", "Creating rename dialog...");
            dialog = new Dialog(appContext);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rename);
            dialog.setTitle("Rename " + noteName);
            break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
            break;
    }
    return dialog;      
}
```

Is there something missing from this? Some questions have talked about having this problem when creating a dialog from `onCreate`, which happens because the activity isn't created yet, but this is coming from a call from a menu object, and the `appContext` variable seems like it is correctly populated in the debugger.

Answer (score 612, accepted):

Instead of :
`Context appContext = this.getApplicationContext();`
you should use a pointer to the activity you're in (probably `this`).

I got bitten by this today too, the annoying part is the `getApplicationContext()` is verbatim from developer.android.com :(

Comment: It's also reported as a bug (although it wasn't when the user posted the question): http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11199

Comment: Just in case this helps anyone - use myActivity.this as your context in a dialog.

Comment: This question and answer turns 3 years old in 2 days. I'm still getting reputation, so i guess Google still haven't fixed their docs...

Comment: This has been fixed in (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: Great, guess this question can go away and finally die of old age then.

Comment: Replaced getApplicationContext() with this , its works fine. Thanx

Comment: @Torp Nope. Not gonna die soon. Take an upvote from a user you helped.

Comment: No, it's still a problem, especially since people will randomly advice you to use `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: So as a clarification, you should use the Activity Context to launch a Dialog rather than some other one.

Comment: This is April of 2016 , and still this exception making application crash on dialog initiation.

Comment: August '16 here, still got it after trying [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944061/how-to-use-number-picker-with-dialog#comment65243784_17944168) answer.

Comment: This is definitely what solved my problem, though I used the `getApplicationContext();`  for the reason that it is recommended to reduced JAVA Heap Memory, and i learned that it is not recommended to use as an instance when it is used for UI/Widgets...

Answer (score 79):

You cannot display an application window/dialog through a Context that is not an Activity. Try passing a valid activity reference

Comment: how? I tried `activity.this` and `activity.getBaseContext()` but no avail. Any help?

Comment: Got it. Directly pass your activity name in it. Without `.this`.

Answer (score 46):

Ditto on the getApplicationContext thing.

The documents on the android site says to use it, but it doesn't work...grrrrr :-P

Just do:

```
dialog = new Dialog(this);
```

**"this"** is usually your Activity from which you start the dialog.

Answer (score 45):

Android documents suggests to use getApplicationContext();

but it will not work instead of that use your current activity while instantiating AlertDialog.Builder or AlertDialog or Dialog...

Ex:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

or

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  AlertDialog.Builder((Your Activity).this);
```

Comment: This helped me out massively. I was trying to create a dialog from within another dialog and just having "AlertDialog.Builder(this);" was giving an error. Thanks!

Comment: (ActivityName.this) is especially useful when trying to create a dialog inside onClick of a button

Comment: My problem is that I'm building a ProgressDialog inside an AlertDialog inside of an Adapter... I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of `getApplicationContext()`, just use `ActivityName.this`

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue where I had another class something like this:

```
public class Something {
  MyActivity myActivity;

  public Something(MyActivity myActivity) {
    this.myActivity=myActivity;
  }

  public void someMethod() {
   .
   .
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(myActivity);
   .
   AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
   alert.show();
  }
}
```

Worked fine most of the time, but sometimes it crashed with the same error.  Then I realise that in `MyActivity` I had...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  public static Something something;

  public void someMethod() {
    if (something==null) {
      something=new Something(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Because I was holding the object as `static`, a second run of the code was still holding the original version of the object, and thus was still referring to the original `Activity`, which no long existed.

Silly stupid mistake, especially as I really didn't need to be holding the object as `static` in the first place...

Answer (score 12):

Just change it into

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert_Categoryitem = 
    new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
```

Instead of

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert_Categoryitem = 
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 9):

Another solution is to set the window type to a system dialog:

```
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

This requires the [`SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

As the docs say:

> Very few applications should use this permission; these windows are intended for system-level interaction with the user.

This is a solution you should only use if you require a dialog that's not attached to an activity.

Comment: This is now deprecated flag from API level 26. Because it allows the developer to play with system window which is not good from user perspective.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `getApplicationContext()` on declaring dialouge

Always use `this` or your `activity.this`

Answer (score 2):

For nested dialogs this issue is very common, It works when

```
AlertDialog.Builder mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
```

is used instead of

```
mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext);
```

this alternative.

Answer (score 2):

This Worked for me--

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b><i><u>Spread Knowledge Unto The Last</u></i></b>"))
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Dismiss",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    }
                }).show();
```

Use

```
ActivityName.this
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    final Context context = this;
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
}
```

This worked for me !!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    Location location;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationlistener;
    ImageView image_view;
    ublic static ProgressDialog progressdialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(Splash.this);
           image_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 100000, 1, locationlistener);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Getting Location plz wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            progressdialog.setMessage("getting Location");
                            progressdialog.show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this,Show_LatLng.class);
//                          }
        });
    }
```

Text here:-
use this for getting `activity` context for `progressdialog`

```
 progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(Splash.this);
```

or `progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);`

use this for getting application context for `BroadcastListener`
     not for `progressdialog`.

```
progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(getBaseContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's said, you need an Activity as context for the dialog, use "YourActivity.this" for a static context or check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665887/3214497) for how to use a dynamic one in a safe mode

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset `dialog` window's type to

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT:
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

Don't forget to use the permission `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`

Answer (score 0):

The best and the safest way to show a 'ProgressDialog' in an AsyncTask, avoiding memory leak problem is to use a 'Handler' with Looper.main().

```
    private ProgressDialog tProgressDialog;
```

then in the 'onCreate'

```
    tProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    tProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
    tProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
```

Now you r done with the setup part. Now call 'showProgress()' and 'hideProgress()' in AsyncTask.

```
    private void showProgress(){
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                tProgressDialog.show();
            }
        }.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }

    private void hideProgress(){
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                tProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }
```