# Android: unable to add window - token null is not for an application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android 1.6: “android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window — token null is not for an application”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window)

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
>   at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
>   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
>   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)

my code:

```
    public class aaaa extends View {
  private WindowManager mWindowManager;
 public aaaa(Context context) {
  super(context);
 }

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon), 0, 0, null);
  super.onDraw(canvas);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  ddd();
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
 }

 void ddd(){
     mWindowManager = WindowManagerImpl.getDefault();

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(50,50);
        lp.x = 50;
        lp.y = 50;

        mWindowManager.addView(this, lp);
   }
```

Comment: A more in-depth explanation and a better title of what your actually asking would help

Answer (score 6):

This exception is usually thrown if you work with an invalid context. What are you passing to the Constructor of your aaa class? If you pass `getApplicationContext()` it may fail. Try passing the context of the activity which is responsible for displaying your view (usually with the reference `this`).