# java.lang.IllegalStateException in Custom Dialog

Tags: android, exception, android-alertdialog, illegalstateexception

I am new to Android and I'm working on custom alert dialog

[image: my custom dialog]

I want to open a another dialog-box on click of edit button and code is below

```
 if (v.getId() == R.id.edt_order) {                                  
        System.out.println(" edit buton click");                    
        System.out.println("Click my Order");
            System.out.println(" edit clickkkkkkkkkkkkkk");
         LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
         View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                 getApplicationContext());

         // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder  
         alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);    

         final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
         .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput); 

         // set dialog message
         alertDialogBuilder
         .setCancelable(false)
         .setPositiveButton("OK",
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                 // get user input and set it to result 
                 // edit text
                 //    result.setText(userInput.getText());

                 System.out.println("Click ok");    
                // insertData(userInput.getText().toString().trim());
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Category added", 5000).show();
                 // loadSpinnerData();
             }
         })
         .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                 dialog.cancel();
             }
         }); 

         // create alert dialog   
          alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

         // show it
         alertDialog.show();                 
    }
```

But I am getting an exception and my log cat output is as follow

```
01-23 14:46:57.438: D/AndroidRuntime(660): Shutting down VM
01-23 14:46:57.448: W/dalvikvm(660): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-23 14:46:57.558: D/dalvikvm(660): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3899 objects / 202144 bytes in 99ms
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.example.demoekot.MainScreen.clickHandler(MainScreen.java:524)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  ... 11 more
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-23 14:46:57.568: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  ... 15 more
```

Even my redcross button is working fine and I've used same code for showing AlertDialog with TextView many times, but I did not get what is going wrong with code. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Now i got whatever i want , but edit and save both are coming  both with overlap . I want to hide edit ( blue button )and make visible save button clearly.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487491/android-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662239/android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-on-buider-s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the documentation at `getApplicationContext()` you find  that you should only use this if you need a `Context` whose lifecycle is separate from the current context. This doesn't apply in  your examples and  use  of `this` object as an object of type className.I think here you can use

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

OR

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ClassNAme.this);
```

Both should work.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

with

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);
```

`Dialog` requires a `Context` reference whose window token is not `null` such as `Activity` reference...

Comment: ..I want to do another thing that , I want INVISIBLE same edit on click of edit button.

Comment: @PriyaSingh add this code `v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` after the `alertDialog.show();` statement...

Comment: I am getting exception

Comment: @PriyaSingh which Exception?

Comment: System.out.println(" edit buton click");                    
   System.out.println("Click my Order");
    System.out.println(" edit clickkkkkkkkkkkkkk");
    img_btn_edit_order_var.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

Comment: I am setting another image after v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) and my effort is as -    v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.save_on));
Is this correct? Please help me i am new in android

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45976/discussion-between-priya-singh-and-gopal-rao)

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you need Context or currentActivity. Then sure it will work.