# When I create a dialog upon a Button click, I get an error. How can I show a dialog upon a Button click?

Tags: android, android-dialog

When I create a dialog upon a Button click, I get an error. How can I show a dialog upon a Button click?

My main class extends Activity.

```
            deleteentry.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new deleteOptionsDialog(getApplicationContext()).show();
                }
            });
    public class deleteOptionsDialog extends Dialog {

            public deleteOptionsDialog(final Context context) {
                super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);

                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                setContentView(R.layout.delete_options_dialog);

                RelativeLayout cameraLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rldelete);
                cameraLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Your question **how can i call dialog method in button clicking** but in your code u can implement click in `RelativeLayout`. Where is u r button?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487491/android-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662239/android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-on-buider-s...

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
new deleteOptionsDialog(getApplicationContext()).show();
```

with

```
new deleteOptionsDialog(YourActivity.this).show();
```

and try to move all your code inside `Constructor` to `onCreate()` method of `Dialog` by overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

try use `new deleteOptionsDialog(YourCurrentActivity.this).show();`
Problem in use `getApplicationContext()` in creating `dialog`

Comment: i am using CurrentActivity.this i didnot get it

Comment: You can post logcat data with exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

For `Dialog` instance you should use Activity context, not `getApplicationContext()` and not `getApplication()`, but `YourActivity.this`

And it's a better idea to instanciate dialog somewhere in onCreate() an later check if it is showing when trying to show once more