# RuntimeException on AlertDialog.show()

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, runtimeexception

I keep getting an exception when I want to display an alertdialog at the beginning of an activity.
I can't figure out why? I really would appreciate an explanation.

The code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (!isInternetConnectionAvailable()) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
        alert.setMessage("TEST DIALOG!!!");
        alert.show();
    }
...
```

> 03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.droidgroup.THMInfo/de.droidgroup.THMInfo.Activities.StartActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at de.droidgroup.THMInfo.Activities.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:82)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   03-19 16:04:33.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15145):     ... 11 more

Comment: Which line is line 82 in your StartActivity.java file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window).

Comment: Thanks man!!! i want to know some thing more, when can we use this and when getApplicationContext()? can you please help me out........

Comment: @amity: the idea is that an application context is something more general than an activity context. An `Activity` (which *extends* `Context`) adds some reference to the window it's shown in. I don't know of other examples like Dialog, but there might be.