# Android AsyncTasks How to Check If activity is still running

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have used `AsyncTasks` with my application, in order to lazy download and update the UI.

For now my `AsyncTasks` updates the UI real simply:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        gender.setText(values[0]);
}
```

My problem is how to check if the activity which the gender `TextView` rendered from, is still available?

If not, I will get an error and my application will shut down.

Comment: not sure can try with  if(null==gender && gender.isShown() )

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can cancel your asynctask in the activity's onDestroy

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    asynctask.cancel(true);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

and when performing changes you check whether your asynctask has been cancelled(activity destroyed) or not

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    if(!isCancelled()) {
         gender.setText(values[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. But there's no guranttee that ondestroy will get called everytime. (For reference link below). How do you cope with that ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4449988/3265444

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem - essentially I was getting a NPE in an async task after the user had destroyed the fragment. After researching the problem on Stack Overflow, I adopted the following solution:

```
volatile boolean running;

public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    running=true;
    ...
    }


public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    running=false;
    ...
}
```

Then, I check "if running" periodically in my async code. I have stress tested this and I am now unable to "break" my activity. This works perfectly and has the advantage of being simpler than some of the solutions I have seen on SO.

Comment: This is simple and really makes sense :) If anyone's thinking about that `volatile` keyword, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/107040/4331787

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
if (!isFinishing()) {
    gender.setText(values[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check whether activity is running or not

```
 if (!isFinishing()) {
  // Do whatever you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though, I have never faced this scenario; I will try to answer your question.

In your case you will need to validate the `Context` passed to `AsyncTask`.

You can perform validation

```
if(null!=mContext)  //Activity still exist!!
{
  gender.setText(values[0]);
}
else //Activity is destroyed
{
   //Take appropriate action!!
}
```

The advantage will be, if the activity is destroyed by the time you reach this statement, your `Context` will automatically become `null` and you can handle the scenario.

Comment: This will not work. Because you keep hard-reference to the activity, it will not be nulled. It will become invalid, but async task will continue to keep reference to the activity.

Answer (score 1):

I will insist that you that if you Activity is not running why don't you cancel the AsyncTask?
That would be a better and feasible solution. If you Application is running say you move from one Activity to another then it won't give error AFAIK.

But, I would insist to cancel the AsyncTask then you'r Activity is not running, you can check AsyncTask is running or not,

```
if(task != null && task.equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING))
task.cancel(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

As [**this**](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html#async-task) part of one training on *Android Developers* suggests, keep a `WeakReference` on the UI element that needs to be updated after task is done and check if the reference is `null` before using it. This helps not only in checking if the UI is still around, but also does not prevent UI elements from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
if (gender) {
   gender.setText(values[0]);
}
```

be enough?

Comment: are you taking for (null==gender)? even for that, no only that's not enough some time

Comment: No, that's not enough. The activity may be finished but gender may still be non-null, and attempts to reference it will fail because the View/Window is no longer active.