# Displaying images in a dialog box

Tags: android

I have an image and I am currently setting it on an imageview.

I want that when the Imageview is clicked , a pop up like a dialog box should appear that displays the image .. Any method how can I acheive this.

```
                Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
                dialog.setTitle("wateva");

                ImageView ivDialog = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivDialog);
                String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                folder = new File(filepath,"checking");

                File fa = new File(folder,"bmp1.png");
                Bitmap bmpa = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fa.getAbsolutePath());
                Log.d("error " , "here");
                ivDialog.setImageBitmap(bmpa);
                dialog.show();
```

Comment: did U searched google: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Answer (score 2):

use **CustomDialog** for that .Create layout that have Imageview and othe Components and set it to Dialog.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);
ImageView imgView=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imagview);
//set image to imgView
dialog.show();
```

Comment: `ImageView ivDialog = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivDialog);`............see my code also

Comment: now i m getting this error  android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: yup i corrected the error

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window