# Can't open optionsMenu programmatically without a user click

Tags: android, menu, optionmenu

In my project i am trying to open the **optionsMenu** programmatically without a click on the **menu** key from the user.  I have tried  **openOptionsMenu()** but it gives me an error like this **android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- ..** why it is... what is the solution for this...

08-13 14:53:02.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 14:53:02.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.veytila.candideye/com.veytila.candideye.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: add related code,and also full logcat

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window

Comment: ok samir i will add that too..

Comment: Sure nick... Can u just help me in this....

Comment: Can you please post your code

Comment: @nick, I have an activity which have a button and i just need to pop up my menu after selecting an image from the gallery....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are doing this in Oncreate or onResume. You will have to call this api only after the window of the activity has been initialized. One way is to post a delayed runnable in your onresume on to ui thread.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for ur replis..... i found solution from mr.Nandeesh's post. I just added the following code and its working...

```
 public void onResume()
{
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
       public void run() { 
           openOptionsMenu(); 
       } 
    }, 500); 

    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: I was pulling my hair off...you made my day!