# Android app crashes when displaying this alertDialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

In the onClick method for my button I have this code to display an alert dialog with an EditText field. However every time I click the button the app crashes. What am i doing wrong?

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alert.setTitle("Enter password")
             .setMessage("Enter your certificate's password");

        final EditText input = new EditText(mContext);

        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
               // code here
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

Here is the log cat:

```
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.SafeApplication(23420): Thread uncaught exception:
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:571)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at com.android.lexperts.email.activity.MessageViewFragmentBase.onImportAttachment(MessageViewFragmentBase.java:819)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at com.android.lexperts.email.activity.MessageViewFragmentBase.onClick(MessageViewFragmentBase.java:1030)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at com.android.lexperts.email.activity.MessageViewFragment.onClick(MessageViewFragment.java:431)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-06 17:00:48.810: E/com.fx.safe.android.safeApplication(23420):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 17:00:48.818: E/ACRA(23420): ACRA caught a BadTokenException exception for com.fx.safe.android. Building report.
```

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: What does the LogCat print?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the crash, but why do you set "PositiveButton twice"? :P

Comment: @Carnal He is not. The second button is a negative button

Comment: For information about logcat, see http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: @Ahmad, he just edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window) question a `WindowManager.BadTokenException` occurs, when you pass in the wrong context.

So change your code to this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
[...]
final EditText input = new EditText(MyActivity.this);
```