# how to use number picker with dialog

Tags: android, dialog, numberpicker

I want to use a number picker for the purpose of getting the discount percentage from the user. once the user enters the sale price, i want a dialog box to appear asking for the discount percentage. I cannot find a way to integrate the numberpicker in the dialog.

Comment: Google **Alert Dialog** and see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27263520/1341526)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have made a small demo of NumberPicker. This may not be perfect but you can use and modify the same.

Use a custom dialog and set the number picker.

More info @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener
{
    private TextView tv;
    static Dialog d ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);// on click of button display the dialog
         b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 show();
            }
            });
           }
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

         Log.i("value is",""+newVal);

     }

    public void show()
    {

         final Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
         d.setTitle("NumberPicker");
         d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
         Button b1 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
         Button b2 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button2);
         final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
         np.setMaxValue(100); // max value 100
         np.setMinValue(0);   // min value 0
         np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
         np.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
         b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              tv.setText(String.valueOf(np.getValue())); //set the value to textview
              d.dismiss();
           }    
          });
         b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              d.dismiss(); // dismiss the dialog
           }    
          });
       d.show();


    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Open" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

dialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:text="Set" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap shot

[image]

Comment: I am having a background image with dotted lines,now I want the user to draw on the dotted lines and I have to validate it whether it is correct or not? Is it possible in canvas and how can I proceed with this?

Comment: @Raghunandan: Is there any way to dismiss the picker on click of center value. I mean, there are 3 values visible if I click on selected value will the numberPicker disappear? Without using Ok/Cancel button. I tried onClick method of NumberPicker but no output. :(

Comment: how hide other numbers (next & previous) only show current one

Comment: @Arjun create a custom view

Comment: @raghunandan can you provide some operation include in it sorry i,m beginner i have created one custom view but its totaly diffrent thank you..

Comment: @Arjun starting my looking at the source code for NumberPicker. Pick the relevant codes and create a custom view that would suit your requirements. Its too broad for comment section

Answer (score 32):

Please try the following code:

```
        RelativeLayout linearLayout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        final NumberPicker aNumberPicker = new NumberPicker(mContext);
        aNumberPicker.setMaxValue(50);
        aNumberPicker.setMinValue(1);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams numPicerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        numPicerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.addView(aNumberPicker,numPicerParams);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Select the number");
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(linearLayout);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                Log.e("","New Quantity Value : "+ aNumberPicker.getValue());

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: This code is perfectly running fine for me also. I want to add one more number picker. I am able to achieve it but not able to format it. Can you guide me to set equal width to two number picker using java only.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. This uses the Android platform buttons, so this is the one to go. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I chose this answer because fiddling with an xml layout just for a dialog seems like too much effort. This one also actually looked better when I implemented it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me - `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Comment: To fix it I had to change alertDialogBuilder instantiation to `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`

Answer (score 15):

This is a shorter variation of the other answers

```
NumberPicker picker = new NumberPicker(context);
picker.setMinValue(1);
picker.setMaxValue(50);

FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(context);
layout.addView(picker, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        Gravity.CENTER));

new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(layout)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
            // do something with picker.getValue()
            picker.getValue();
        })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
        .show();
```

Comment: It works property. I'm using into an EditText, setting focusable to false and setting the OnClickListener make the view "single" clickable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a DialogFragment implementing onCreateDialog method which returns alert dialog containing the NumberPicker view.
Instantiate the dialog fragment in the activity where you need to show number picker dialog and show it.

Make the host activity implement NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener interface so that positive and negative button click event handlers in dialog can pass the current value from NumberPicker by calling the interface onValueChange method.

For more information you can see http://www.zoftino.com/android-numberpicker-dialog-example .

```
public class NumberPickerDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener valueChangeListener;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            final NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(getActivity());

            numberPicker.setMinValue(20);
            numberPicker.setMaxValue(60);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Choose Value");
            builder.setMessage("Choose a number :");

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    valueChangeListener.onValueChange(numberPicker,
                            numberPicker.getValue(), numberPicker.getValue());
                }
            });

        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                valueChangeListener.onValueChange(numberPicker,
                        numberPicker.getValue(), numberPicker.getValue());
            }
        });

        builder.setView(numberPicker);
        return builder.create();
    }

    public NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener getValueChangeListener() {
        return valueChangeListener;
    }

    public void setValueChangeListener(NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener valueChangeListener) {
        this.valueChangeListener = valueChangeListener;
    }
}
```