# How to add Up and Down arrows to android EditText in Android

Tags: android

how to add arrows to editText like these? [image]

Is there a way to show the [number picker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) in EditText ?

Comment: use `ImageButton` for this.

Comment: please take a look `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944061/how-to-use-number-picker-with-dialog`

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file

```
<NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

You can call setOnValueChangedListener method on number picker object to add value change listener to NumberPicker.
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.numberpicker);

       NumberPicker np = findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);

       np.setMinValue(2);
       np.setMaxValue(20);

       np.setOnValueChangedListener(onValueChangeListener);
    }

    NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener onValueChangeListener =
            new     NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int i1) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "selected number "+numberPicker.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom view composed of an `EditText` (or `TextView`) and 2 `ImageButton`'s. This should get you started:

1. Create the class:

   ```
    public class MyNumberPickerView extends ConstraintLayout {

        private ImageButton incrementButton;
        private ImageButton decrementButton;
        private EditText numberEditText;

        public MyNumberPickerView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public MyNumberPickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public MyNumberPickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onFinishInflate() {
            super.onFinishInflate();
            incrementButton = findViewById(R.id.increment);
            decrementButton = findViewById(R.id.decrement);
            numberEditText = findViewById(R.id.number);
        }

        // expose public functions for listeners, setting a number, etc.
    }
   ```
2. Create a layout:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.company.app.ui.common.MyNumberPickerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/increment"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/number"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/decrement"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/increment"
            tools:text="99" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/decrement"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/number" />

    </com.company.app.ui.common.MyNumberPickerView>
   ```

3. Include your custom view in other layouts like:

   ```
    <include android:id="@+id/numberpicker"                     
        layout="@layout/view_mynumberpicker"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ```
4. And use it after inflation:

   ```
    MyNumberPickerView myNumberPickerView = findViewById(R.id.numberpicker);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have some project like there, but i am not finish the sorce code, maybe you can found good ide. sorry bad english.
Check my project https://github.com/AgungDev/ClockScrollComponent

[image: https://github.com/AgungDev/ClockScrollComponent]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31427340)