# run time exception in progress bar

Tags: android

```
if (Commons.HaveNetworkConnection()) {
                if ((txt_USERNAME.getText().toString().trim() != null && txt_USERNAME
                        .getText().toString().length() != 0)// username
                                                            // check
                        && (txt_PASSWORD.getText().toString().trim() != null && txt_PASSWORD
                                .getText().toString().length() != 0)) {// password
                    // check
                    pd = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "","Please wait...");
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "data"+txt_USERNAME + txt_PASSWORD, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Thread thread = new Thread(LoginActivity.this);
                    thread.start();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Invalid username or password",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Commons.setOnlineAlert();
            }

}catch(Exception e){Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"problem in onclick 1 block"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        }

        private Context getContext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    });
```

when i click on login button then runtime exception occur

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Please help me how we can solve this problem

Comment: Where you are dismiss or cancel your progress bar ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Context` method you should actually return the context of activity not null

> ```
>     private Context getContext() {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         return LoginActivity.this.getApplicationContext();
>     }
> ```

And set this in your `Toast` message as below:

```
      Toast.makeText(getContext(), "data"+txt_USERNAME + txt_PASSWORD, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

your are showing toast message with null..
 Remove this method

```
 private Context getContext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
```

and in this line

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "data"+txt_USERNAME + txt_PASSWORD, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

change to

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data"+txt_USERNAME + txt_PASSWORD, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```