# showing a progress bar or dialog from inside a custom adapter

Tags: android, progress-bar, progressdialog

I have a listview with images.  The user can click on the thumbnail and a larger image will be download and displayed in an ImageView inside a new activity.

The onclick is inside my GetView in my adapter:

```
holder.iconImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try{

           //load the image
        String name = folderName.get(position).toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ImageViewLarge.class);
        i.putExtra("link", link);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);


        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context, "errror: " + e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

});
```

It can take a few seconds to display the image, so I would like to have either a dialog, or a round progress spinning circle displayed on the screen while the image is loaded.

How can I do this if my onclick is inside my adapter?

I tried this inside the adapter but got an error:

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Opening Image","Please wait..");

"Unable to add window — token null is not for an application”
```

Comment: That should be the responsibility of ImageViewLarge.class. Because there you are downloading the image I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this code it is working fine.

```
viewHolder.text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait.....");
            dialog.show();
            // you can add here  your stuffs
        }
    });
```

Comment: still get this error when I click on an image in the listview: "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window— token null is not for an application”

Comment: It's working fine in my project.I hope you adapter not getting proper context Use activity context instead of application context.

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window

Comment: This is how my adapter gets its context:   public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> images, ArrayList folderName){

        this.context = c;

Comment: and then its called like this:  adapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), pix, paths);
            lstView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: yes pass like this- new ImageAdapter(this,pix,paths);