# How to open Dialog Box when broadcast receive in android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How to open `Dialog` when phone state is receive. Because whenever a `State` is received it results in the following error:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

How can I solve this problem?

Phone State is Idle then i call Dialog. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my code.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mcontext);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                        dialog.setTitle("Android Custom Dialog Box");
                        final EditText et_remark = (EditText) dialog
                                .findViewById(R.id.et_remark);

                        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog
                                .findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
                        dialogButton
                                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        String remark = et_remark.getText()
                                                .toString();

                                        if (call_duration.equals("0")) {


                                            Toast.makeText(mcontext,
                                                    " miss",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                    .show();
                                        } else {

                                            if (cType.equals("OUTGOING")) {


                                                Toast.makeText(
                                                        mcontext,
                                                        " out ",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                        .show();

                                            } else {

                                                Toast.makeText(mcontext,
                                                        " inc",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                        .show();
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: [refere]  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window . you will get the right solution

Comment: Post your onReceive() method code.

Comment: post what have you tried so far

Comment: Where does the mContext value come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broadcast receive is app service(intent service). The [intent service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) have a few limitations the first one and most important is 'It can't interact directly with your user interface'.

Then you have a alternative you can try to work with handle if your app it's open and then the handle captures message and throws dialog from handle.
Tell me if I helped you and good programming!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Broadcastreceiver

```
public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



    private String incomingNumber;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if  (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

             // get the phone number 
             incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Disp_Alert_dialog.class); 
               // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                //i.putExtra("Number", incomingNumber);
                //i.putExtra("type", "incoming");
                context.startActivity(i);
        //   Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" +incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call



        } else  {


            // This code will execute when the call is disconnected
       //  Toast.makeText(context, "Detected call hangup event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }


}
```

Alertclass.java

```
public class Disp_Alert_dialog extends Activity{

    private String nums;
    private String outnum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent iin= getIntent();

        nums=iin.getStringExtra("Number");




    //  Toast.makeText(Disp_Alert_dialog.this, "Got it"+nums, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


        builder
            .setTitle("")
            .setMessage("")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                {
                   Intent intent=new Intent(Disp_Alert_dialog.this,MainActivity.class);

                   intent.putExtra("Nums", nums);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   Disp_Alert_dialog.this.finish();
                    /*HomeFragment fragobj = new HomeFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("Nums", nums);
                    // set Fragmentclass Arguments

                    fragobj.setArguments(bundle);*/

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```