# how to fix WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: android, fragment

I need to change my fragment, but when i do changeFragment i got that exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

my code:

```
 ((MainActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(new HomeFragment(), 
 HomeFragment.TAG);
```

im doing something wrong?

Comment: Does your MainActivity contains HomeFragment ?

Comment: Yeah! I call them in other activity with the same code.

Comment: you need to pass the context of that activity in which you are calling the fragment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 1.6: "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window)

Comment: Yeahhh! Im try to go to HomeFragment by a dialog click. @Redman

Comment: try dismissing the dialog before you go , can you add HomeFragment code too